# KeyError with using get_group in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have time series as shown below:

```
                   date_time  system_load    date    month_year  year  month  day  hour   load_group
0     2013-01-01 00:00:00     17.2      2013-01-01    2013-01  2013      1    1     0  (15, 20]
1     2013-01-01 01:00:00     16        2013-01-01    2013-01  2013      1    1     1  (15, 20]
2     2013-01-01 02:00:00     15        2013-01-01    2013-01  2013      1    1     2  (15, 20]
3     2013-01-01 03:00:00     15        2013-01-01    2013-01  2013      1    1     3  (15, 20]
4     2013-01-01 04:00:00     14        2013-01-01    2013-01  2013      1    1     4  (12, 15]
...                   ...          ...         ...        ...   ...    ...  ...   ...             ...
70123 2020-12-31 19:00:00     23        2020-12-31    2020-12  2020     12   31    19  (20, 25]
...                   ...          ...         ...        ...   ...    ...  ...   ...             ...
```

I want to get only the category (20,50] using "get_group" function as follow:

```
df0.groupby('load_group').get_group('(20, 25]')
```

I don't know how solve that problem.

I got the following :   "KeyError: '(20, 25]'"

Also the same error using the following code:

```
df0.groupby('month_year').get_group('2016-07')
```

"KeyError: '2016-07'

I print df0.info()

```
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------       --------------  -----         
 0   date_time    70128 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 1   system_load  70128 non-null  float64       
 2   date         70128 non-null  object        
 3   month_year   70128 non-null  period[M]     
 4   year         70128 non-null  int64         
 5   month        70128 non-null  int64         
 6   day          70128 non-null  int64         
 7   hour         70128 non-null  int64         
 8   load_group   70001 non-null  category
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must convert the group names to the exact object types which they were stored. Note the `dtypes` in your `df0.info()`:

- `month_year` is `period[M]` instead of `str`.
- `load_group` is a category column containing `pd.Interval` elements, not `str` elements. Although this is not shown explicitly, but that should be how the data was normally produced. If they were `str`, your code would have worked.

## Restore Data and Dtypes

The following code reproduces your `df0.info()`. Here I use `df` instead of `df0`.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
date_time            system_load    date      month_year  year  month  day  hour   load_group
2013-01-01 00:00:00     17.2      2013-01-01     2013-01  2013      1    1     0   (15, 20]
2013-01-01 01:00:00     16        2013-01-01     2013-01  2013      1    1     1   (15, 20]
2013-01-01 02:00:00     15        2013-01-01     2013-01  2013      1    1     2   (15, 20]
2013-01-01 03:00:00     15        2013-01-01     2013-01  2013      1    1     3   (15, 20]
2013-01-01 04:00:00     14        2013-01-01     2013-01  2013      1    1     4   (12, 15]
2020-12-31 19:00:00     23        2020-12-31     2020-12  2020     12   31    19   (20, 25]
"""), sep=r"\s{2,}", engine='python')

df["date_time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date_time"])

# restore interval type for the elements
df["load_group"] = df["load_group"].apply(lambda s: pd.Interval(int(s[1:3]), int(s[5:7]), "right"))
# restore category type for the column
df["load_group"] = df["load_group"].astype("category")

# restore monthly period type    
df["month_year"] = pd.to_datetime(df["month_year"]).dt.to_period("M")
```

## Code

### Interval Column

```
gp = pd.Interval(20, 25, "right")   # (20, 25]
print(df.groupby("load_group").get_group(gp))

Out[138]: 
            date_time  system_load        date  ... day  hour  load_group
5 2020-12-31 19:00:00         23.0  2020-12-31  ...  31    19    (20, 25]

[1 rows x 9 columns]
```

### Period Column

```
gp = pd.Period(pd.to_datetime("2013-01"), freq="M")
# or equivalently, pd.Period(freq="M", year=2013, month=1)

print(df.groupby('month_year').get_group(gp))

Out[140]: 
            date_time  system_load        date  ... day  hour  load_group
0 2013-01-01 00:00:00         17.2  2013-01-01  ...   1     0    (15, 20]
1 2013-01-01 01:00:00         16.0  2013-01-01  ...   1     1    (15, 20]
2 2013-01-01 02:00:00         15.0  2013-01-01  ...   1     2    (15, 20]
3 2013-01-01 03:00:00         15.0  2013-01-01  ...   1     3    (15, 20]
4 2013-01-01 04:00:00         14.0  2013-01-01  ...   1     4    (12, 15]
[5 rows x 9 columns]
```